# dailymotion video is not playing with linux based embedded system

Tags: qt, http, media-player, dailymotion-api

daily motion videos are not playing in my Linux based embedded system.

i am using qt4.8 browser.

server returns forbidden error (http://www.dailymotion.com/stream)

i want to know the reason for this error. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use http://dailymotion.com/tv , this one works. Your link is the wrong one (old one).